# Algebra step question for a resistor and capacitor in series

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am not sure how to go from step 3 to step 4. Why is there an r in the denominator?

We start off saying that

$$Z_i = \frac{1}{s\times c}+ r\tag 1$$

Then we may simplify so that

$$=\frac{r\times s \times c}{s \times c}+\frac{1}{s \times c} \tag 2$$

Now taking the common denom

$$=\frac{r \times s \times c}{s \times c} \tag 3$$

Then the solution is somehow as follows:

$$Z_i = \frac{r}{s}\times(s+\frac{1}{r \times c}) \tag 4$$

We want to get the s by itself because it is eventually replaced with both the values $0$ and $\infty$.

Comment: Shouldn't be $r \times s \times c + 1$ in the numerator of the expression in step 3?

Comment: Yes, you are right! and in order to factor out an R we must add it to the numerator of $\frac{1}{c}$